# Missed ordering 10uH inductors for ICs, do I need them?

Tags: inductor

Well dumb me apparently forgot to order these 10μH inductors. I'm assuming the L and the C and the R are used for band-pass-filtering/stabilizing the input voltages. I really don't want to make an order from Digikey just for these inductors. The shipping costs will already be magnitudes more than the prices for these components. I'm thinking of just replacing them with wires. Is this OK?

[image: Not another Digikey order please]

Comment: Maybe, depends on what else is using the power rails, and how much of a problem conducted emissions are in the design. 10uH seems awfully big for power filtering.

Comment: the chip on the right is AT91SAM9N12, so a 400MHz ARM processor. The datasheet mentioned it's for stabilizing current fluctuations to within a range (if I remember correctly). Notice there's one on each of VDDOSC and VDDPLL.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah that will probably work for proto.  You may notice some performance issues depending in what this chip does.  Also as a poor mans substitute since this is low current you could use a low value resistor to make an RC filter, or if you have some ferrites laying around you could try that.

Also if you're in the US I've found the us mail shipping option at digi is way cheaper, and also pretty fast.  They're right by the airport out there in Minnesota so it ships out fairly quickly.  Then you'll have a backup on the way without breaking the bank.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a prototype and space constraints aren't too stringent why not a hand-wound air-core inductor?

[image]

30 turns on a 1cm diameter gives you the required value. Not the smallest of components but still doable. You also don't need to worry anymore about core saturation.

Comment: good suggestion, but space is 0603 SMD as this is for a BGA ARM chip